# How to access a certain GET data in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am currently writing an adress book and using a framework (CakePHP) an MVC for the first time. Unfortunately I have some trouble.

I want to realize the following:

In case the URL is

```
/contacts/view/
```

I want to show all contacts in a list. In case there is an id given after /view/, e.g.

```
/contacts/view/1
```

I just want to display the contact with the id 1. (complete different view/design than in the first case)

My ContactsController.php is the following

```
public function view($id = null){
    if(!$this->id){        
        /*
         * Show all users
         */
        $this->set('mode', 'all');
        $this->set('contacts', $this->Contact->find('all'));
    } else {
        /*
         * Show a specific user
         */
        $this->set('mode','single');

        if(!$this->Contact->findByid($id)){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('User not found'));
        } else {
            $this->set('contact', $this->Contact->findByid($id));
        };
    }        
}
```

But "$this->mode" is always set as "all". How can I check whether the id is set or not?
I really want to avoid "ugly" URL-schemes like ?id=1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "But "$this->mode" is always set as "all"" --- that's presumably because `if(!$this->id){` condition is always `true`. How is it relevant to the url parameter and `$id` variable?

Comment: I thought the parameters given in the view function would be parsed as arguments given in the URL.
so view($id=null, $param2=null) would be /view/$id/$param2

Comment: so? How is it related to what I said? Do you realize the difference between `$this->id` and `$id`?

Comment: I think I got the difference. $this->id is in my case never set and $id is just a (given) parameter of the function. Both are different variables.
But with "if(!$id) ..." it doesn't work neither. I don't know how to access the GET-data after /view/

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

Comment: Thanks! I get stucked when I read the page before, but I printed the array of $this->request and got the request array.
I can access the needed data with $this->request->params['pass'][0]
Thats what I needed, thank you :)

Comment: @zerkms is right, there is not much more to say here. Oh, well, maybe: [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params) regarding the "ugly"

Comment: Seems to be interesting but quite complicated. I'll try it when I have more experience with CakePHP. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I suggest to read the blog tutorial again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only meeting the if part and its not going to else part. Use (!$id)..

Answer (score 0):

$_GET data is retrieved through the URL. In CakePHP this means it's accessed through that method's parameters.

I'm arbitrarily picking names, so please follow! If you're in the guests controller and posting to the register method you'd access it like this

```
function register($param1, $param2, $param3){

}
```

Each of these params is the GET data, so the URL would look something like

```
www.example.com/guests/param1/param2/param3
```

So now for your question `How can I check whether the id is set or not?`

There are a couple of possibilities. If you want to check if the ID exists, you can do something like

```
$this->Model->set = $param1
if (!$this->Model->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
}
else{
    //conduct search
}
```

Or you can just search based on whether or not the parameter is set

```
if(isset($param1)){ //param1 is set
    $search = $this->Model->find('all','conditions=>array('id' => $param1)));
}
else{
    $search = $this->Model->find('all');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only change the conditions not the whole block of code like

```
public function view($id = null){
    $conditions = array();
    $mode = 'all';

    if($id){
        $conditions['Contact.id'] = $id;
        $mode = 'single';
    }

    $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));

    $this->set(compact('contacts', 'mode'));
}
```